# Examples of sets that are an "essence" of another set in predicate logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, examples-counterexamples

In my lecture course on Set Theory, the "essence of a set" is defined in the following way:

> **Essence:** we say that $x$ is an essence of $y$ if:
> $$\forall w \space (w \in x) \leftrightarrow (y \in w) $$
> In other words, every element of $x$ contains $y$ and every set containing $y$ is an element of $x$.

Are there any examples of sets that have this particular property. I haven't been able to find any references of this particular concept outside of my lecture course, so finding specific examples of this property has been difficult. If there are no examples of sets with this specific property, I would also be interested in a justification as to why this is the case.

Comment: Your verbal description seems to say $\forall w (w \color{red}{{} \subseteq {}} x \leftrightarrow y \in w)$ instead.

Comment: You're right. That was a mistake.  I've edited the post now. Thanks @L.F.

Comment: Are you working in ZFC or some other set theory?  If such a pair $(x, y)$ were to exist, then $\bigcup x$ would necessarily contain every set, which is not possible in ZFC.

Comment: Yes, this is in ZFC. I'm not sure I follow your comment though @L.F.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a pair $(x, y)$ of sets does not exist in ZFC by Russell's paradox.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there are sets $x$ and $y$ such that
$$
\forall w \; (w \in x \iff y \in w). \label{*} \tag{*}
$$
Let
$$
U = \bigcup_{s \in x} s.
$$
We show that $U$ contains every set as follows.
Suppose that $r$ is an arbitrary set.
Then, $r \in \{y, r\}$ and $\{y, r\} \in x$ by \eqref{*}.
Therefore,
$$ r \in \bigcup_{s \in x} s = U. $$
[Russell's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) shows that a set containing every set does not exist in ZFC.